# CSS Menu with background-image. How to make it scale up and down correctly with % and EM

Tags: css, responsive-design, background-image

I have this menu; http://fhemmel.host56.com/stack/
I want it to scale up and down as i resize the window, but still appear correctly with % and EM. I've tried to fix the x and y position as well as the base position to make it appear, but I cant get it to appear.

Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need it for mobiles :) The best way is to do it with % and then everything will be automatical, BUT for this instead of having image as background you would need to do them as  HTML tag. You can't rescale background element (ok, you can do it with transform: scale, but it don't help you in this case).

Then you will have something like this http://jsfiddle.net/55m8j/1/ :

```
<nav>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html" id="side1"><img src="image1.jpg"></a></li>             
    <li><a href="index.html" id="side2"><img src="image2.jpg"></a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html" id="side3"><img src="image3.jpg"></a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html" id="side4"><img src="image4.jpg"></a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html" id="side5"><img src="image5.jpg"></a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

and in CSS

```
nav ul {list-style-type: none;}
nav ul li {width: 20%; float: left;}
nav ul li a {display: block;}
nav ul li a img {width: 100%; }
```

Other way is just to make menu not as images. You can render font with squirell, add text-shadow, some gradients, border and the result will be similar :)

Comment: Not really correct semantically to have `img` in this menu. The CSS3 solution is better (gradients, etc) or a `background-size` solution.

Comment: You have right. It's not great soultion. Completly forgot about background-size, cause it's seems to be the best solution after all.

Comment: The problem with `background-size` compared to your solution is that its support is not perfect (IE8-), so a JS fallback must be provided.